# How to capture the beginning of a filename using a regex in Bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a number of files in a directory named `edit_file_names.sh`, each containing a `?` in their name. I want to use a Bash script to shorten the file names right before the `?`. For example, these would be my current filenames:

```
test.file.1?twagdsfdsfdg
test.file.2?
test.file.3?.?
```

And these would be my desired filenames after running the script:

```
test.file.1
test.file.2
test.file.3
```

However, I can't seem to capture the beginning of the filenames in my regex to use in renaming the files. Here is my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd test_file_name_edit/

regex="(^[^\?]*)"

for filename in *; do
  $filename =~ $regex
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done
```

At this point I'm just attempting to print off the beginnings of each filename so that I know that I'm capturing the correct string, however, I get the following error:

```
./edit_file_names.sh: line 7: test.file.1?twagdsfdsfdg: command not found

./edit_file_names.sh: line 7: test.file.2?: command not found

./edit_file_names.sh: line 7: test.file.3?.?: command not found
```

How can I fix my code to successfully capture the beginnings of these filenames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex as such may not be the best tool for this job. Instead, I'd suggest using bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=(test.file.1?twagdsfdsfdg test.file.2? test.file.3?.?)

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  echo "${f} shortens to ${f%%\?*}"
done
```

which prints

```
test.file.1?twagdsfdsfdg shortens to test.file.1
test.file.2? shortens to test.file.2
test.file.3?.? shortens to test.file.3
```

Here, `${f%%\?*}` expands `f` and trims the longest suffix that matches a `?` followed by any characters (the `?` must be escaped since it's a wildcard character).

Answer (score 1):

You miss the test command `[[ ]]` :

```
for filename in *; do
  [[ $filename =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done
```